# Was Leia ever referred to as "Leia Skywalker"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names, princess-leia

Preamble:   A lot of discussion on the parentage of Rey and Ben takes it for granted the "Leia is a Skywalker", which clearly she is by lineage.

## In any canon, did Leia go by or get called by the name *Skywalker* after she learned her true parentage?

I'm not talking about cases where she is called ***a*** *Skywalker*.   She would have to be called *Leia Skywalker* or *General Skywalker*, etc.

(I'm assuming it is no for Disney canon, but if not, that answer would take priority.)

Comment: Why would she? Most adopted children don't switch back to their birth name after learning who their biological parents were.

Comment: possibly in new canon novel "Bloodline" since her lineage only became public knowledge during that time, but I'm not finding anything yet

Comment: @JAB, well, maybe because it's an auspicious name. Maybe because Alderaan was destroyed. Maybe because in some continuity she became a Jedi so was more attached to that aspect of her lineage. It doesn't matter why. Why are you casting judgment? Why are you assuming your sensibilities apply to the GFFA?

Comment: I should add: Maybe people are thinking I'm implying that she would necessarily do that just because of learning her true parentage. No. I simply meant she couldn't possibly do it before because she didn't know.

Comment: [BTW](http://www.declassifiedadoptee.com/2013/05/i-am-adopted-reunited-and-i-changed-my.html)   (I add this only because there are **five!** upvotes on the *Why would she?* comment and I see those five people as casting judgment over the question where the mere fact of asking a question is not casting judgment. So I see it as hypocritical.)

Comment: I've checked again and I can't find any additional info to add to my answer. Is there anything else you think I should address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: In Legends, the Noghri call her “Lady Vader”.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Main Canon

Within the Disney canon, that's a big **no**. She went by Princess Leia Organa for most of her life, then *General* Leia Organa after the destruction of the Empire.

### Wacky low level canon

The 2009 [Wizards of the West Coast: Star Wars Miniature set](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/miniatures) (licensed by LucasFilm) featured this charming figurine and along with it, a 'battle-card' that said

> **Leia Skywalker**, Jedi Knight.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

And in the [Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_The_Visual_Dictionary), we learn Leia's full name

> *Overcome by grief for what has transpired since the kidnap of
> Palpatine. Bail watches medtechs at the Polis Massa facility struggle
> to save Padmé’s life after they have delivered her twins. After her
> death. Bail offers to raise **Leia Amidala Skywalker** in the house of his
> wife, the Queen of Alderaan.*

Comment: Many miniatures games use the convention of "specific name" to determine uniqueness. For game purposes "Leia Organa", "Leia Organa-Solo", and "Leia Skywalker" would be three *different* people and could all show up in the same player's force.

Comment: Seeing as this has spawned a sub-question; where in canon does Leia use the name "Organa-Solo"? I know it was common in Legends, but I can't recall running across it in new materials

Comment: @JasonBaker - I can't find any main canon references, I've edited accordingly.