# Why did Leia keep Organa as her last name?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, princess-leia

I have been re-watching the Star Wars movies as to get ready for the Last Jedi and in the Force Awakens, Leia is introduced as Leia Organa.

Is there a reason as why she chose to keep the Organa last name and not taking the Skywalker one?

I know she has been adopted and raised by Bail and Breha Organa but I wonder if her decisions was only based on her feelings or for other reasons? The Organa name has probably more impact in politics than the Skywalker one but there must be a real reason.

Comment: Dunno. Maybe they don’t have the same naming conventions in the Galaxy Far, Far Away as in certain Earth cultures?;)

Comment: It's also possible she kept it out of respect for her adoptive-father and -family who died during the destruction of Alderaan, maybe because she'd begun her political career with the name and it gave her more political sway

Comment: Also, after marrying Han Solo, she has an "Organa-Solo" double name for some time.

Comment: "The Organa name has probably more impact in politics than the Skywalker one but there must be a real reason" - Why don't you consider that a real reason?

Comment: And by the time she found out that her last name was Skywalker, she also became aware that she was Darth Vader's daughter. Would that count as a real reason?

Comment: Because her biological father is a monster who killed billions, perhaps?

Comment: Given that she was legally adopted, is there any special reason why she wouldn't keep her adoptive family name?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157546/besides-leia-organa-solo-are-there-other-example-of-married-names)

Comment: The real question is : Why was Luke called Skywalker if the goal was to hide from Darth Vader? It seems perfectly logical that Leia would be called Organa.

Comment: @Adamant Indeed. Though... maybe they have the same naming conventions as certain Earth cultures. Here in Spain neither men nor women change any of our two surnames (more for nobility and royalty) when married.

Comment: @TimSparrow source?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Empire's End: Aftermath, there is this sentence.

> The child's name is Ben, and he takes his father's last name, even as Leia keeps only her own family name, Organa.

Even though she is sister to Luke Skywalker, she considers Organa to be her family name, as they raised her and loved her.

In Bloodline (Star Wars) she says this after it is publicly revealed that Darth Vader was her father.

> "Only my birth father" she insisted. "My *real* father - the only father I ever knew or wanted - was Bail Organa of Alderaan.

Also, while she loves Luke, she isn't much of a fan of Darth Vader, so I'm sure there was no sentimental feeling to taking the Skywalker name. Again from Bloodline:

> He made me watch my planet die. He froze Han in carbonite and sold him to Jabba the Hutt. He cut off my brother's hand and nearly took his life. And he tortured me, Ransolm. He tortured me until I screamed and shook and thought I would die just from the pain alone. Did you bother to ask yourself how it might feel, to realize the person who'd done all that to you was *your father*? Can you imagine how terrible it is to realize all you'll ever know of your birth father is how much he enjoyed making you suffer?

Your question is specifically about her not taking the Skywalker name, but it could easily be inferred that she also did not take Solo's name (if taking the name of a spouse is even normal in the Star Wars universe) on the merits of her already established Organa name in politics and honoring her adopted parents.

Comment: "He may have been your father, boy, but he wasn't your daddy." - Yondu

Comment: [On that last point](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157546/besides-leia-organa-solo-are-there-other-example-of-married-names)

Comment: Leia did take Hans name, she was Leia Organa Solo after marrying.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot He put it slightly more eloquently: "He may've been your father, boy, but he ain't your daddy."

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I didn't really care about Solo last name. She could have been Skywalker-Solo or Organa-Solo, the point was more about Skywalker/Organa last name. I wanted some materials that describes her feelings or her choice, which you provided :)

Answer (score -1):

Well for one the reason Leia was raised by Senator Organa was because Senator Amidala (Leia’s mother) was very close with the Organa and he helped the Republic as well as the Rebellion after the fall of the Republic.

As of Leia keeping the name “Organa” it was most likely for her own safety. Remember Kylo Ren is a Skywalker and is well aware of her mother. Because of this obvious knowledge of the name Skywalker it is likely that leaders of the empire such as Admirals, Moffs, and Generals, or more accurately Supreme Leader Snoke would attack the rebellion forces at first notice of the name Skywalker.